# Rails port of testing environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, port

I'd like to test the HTTP API of our Rails app using Faraday and RSpec. Faraday needs the host url + port. Unfortunately the port of the testing environment does always change. How do I access the current port programmatically in the spec?

Answer (score 13):

If using Capybara you can set the port in the spec_helper.rb like so:

```
Capybara.server_port = 1234
```

See also: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/123

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately it does not work for us that way. We don't use Capybara in that specific test. We just call `Faraday.new(:url => "http://localhost:3033")` for example. Do we have to call `visit` or something like that?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use RSpec + Capybara for testing your API?

See http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/acceptance-testing-using-capybaras-new-rspec-dsl/.

Comment: In which context do you use Faraday? (controller-spec? model-spec? integration-spec?)

Comment: @fpauser I don't understand why you don't understand... I am also in a case where capybara does not match my needs.

Comment: Capybara specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840428/port-of-the-rails-app-when-running-cucumber-tests

Answer (score 5):

There's probably more than one way to do this, but this is working for me right now:

## The command

```
port = `lsof -p #{Process.pid} -ai TCP -as TCP:LISTEN -Fn | grep ^n | cut -c 4- | uniq`.strip
```

Note that you'll have to do this at some point *after* the app has loaded - i.e., you can't use this in your `environment.rb` or `application.rb` file.

## The explanation

Basically what this command does is as follows:

- `lsof` is the Unix command for LiSt Open Files
- `-p #{Process.pid}` limits it to the current process (i.e., your test web server instance)
- `-ai TCP` limits it to "files" of type TCP (i.e., open TCP ports). (Note: the `-a` is to make it *AND* the search with the pid one - the default, using just `-i` would *OR* the search)
- `-as TCP:LISTEN` limits to just TCP ports that are being *listened* on (as opposed to any open port - like your app's connection to Postgres for example)
- `-Fn` tells it to only output the "name" column, which in this case will be the IP/port that is being listened on

The output of that part by itself will be something like this:

```
p12345
n*:5001
n*:5001
```

The first line, starting with `p` is the process ID. There's no way to suppress this.
The next 2 lines (not sure why it can output multiples, but we'll take care of it in a minute) are the "name" column (hence `n`), followed by the IP + port. In our case (and I imagine yours as well, in a test environment), the web server listens on *all* available local IPs, thus `*`. Then it tells us that the port is, in this case 5001.

Finally, we pipe it through...
* `grep ^n` to eliminate the first line (the process id)
* `cut` to say "cut from columns 4 on" - i.e., remove the `n*:` to return *just* the port, and
* `uniq` to just get the one instance

(It will also have a trailing newline, thus the `strip` call.)

## The usage

In my case, I'm using this in my Cucumber `env.rb` thusly, to reconfigure the URL options for ActiveMailer so my email links get generated properly as working links in test:

port = `lsof -p #{Process.pid} -ai TCP -as TCP:LISTEN -Fn | grep ^n | cut -c 4- | uniq`.strip

MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host] = "0.0.0.0:#{port}"
end

No doubt you could do the same thing in a helper/config for Rspec as well.