# Port of the Rails app when running Cucumber tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, port

Is there a way to get, in the test, the port in which the rails app is running during cucumber test? I tried Capybara.server_port but that's nil.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cucumber / Capybara -- how to get the host and port of the current execution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791601/cucumber-capybara-how-to-get-the-host-and-port-of-the-current-execution)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the local port a rails instance is running on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554267/how-to-find-the-local-port-a-rails-instance-is-running-on)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using the selenium driver, the port can be found on:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.rack_server.port
```

and when using the webkit driver, it can be found on:

```
Capybara.current_session.driver.server_port
```

Alternative, you can set

```
Capybara.server_port
```

to a known value and use that.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that if you're using rack-test, the default Capybara driver, then there's isn't actually any real web server running to make requests to.

If you want to view your app as Cucumber/Capybara would, then you'd need to start it up manually on a chosen port:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails s -p 4000
```

And then have something like this in env.rb:

```
Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.app_host = "http://localhost:4000"
end
```