# How do you set the server port in Rails system tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, system-testing, actiondispatch

The Rails server starts on a different port every time you run the system tests.

Is there any way to specify which port this should be and not have it change on every run?

I would like to test clicking a link from an ActionMailer message in my system test. I need to specify a host in my test environment config file for this and I need a static port number for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6807498/338859

> If using Capybara you can set the port in the spec_helper.rb like so:
>
> ```rb
> Capybara.server_port = 1234
> ```

Also see this blog post, it also has some mentions for emails: [System of a test: Proper browser testing in Ruby on Rails](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/system-of-a-test-setting-up-end-to-end-rails-testing)